# 区切りのあるテキストと区切りのない文章を開きタブクリックで切り替えると、区切りのあるテキストにファイルパスが入力される

Tags: emeditor

お世話様です。
区切りのあるテキストと、区切りのない文章を開き、
タブクリックで切り替えると、区切りのあるテキストにファイルパスが入力されます。
これってどこかの設定で規制出来るのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

この問題は、v20.9.2 以上で修正されています。v20.9.1 のままでこの問題を回避するには、セル ツール バーの右端にあるボタンをクリックして表示されるメニューで、[セル ツール バーを自動的に表示/非表示を切り替える] をクリックして、この項目のチェック マークを消してください。